# SSRS nested parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to figure out how to do "nested" parameters and display a different prompt when different options are selected.

For example, this parameter (@prmLimit)

[image]

When someone selects one of those, I want to do a separate prompt that will contain a list of either clients, abstractors, or examiners, and have the report display ONLY that client, etc.

Comment: value retuned by this parameter should be fed into the dataset of  the next drop down you would like to be populated and so on....

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a dataset to pull all clients, abstractors, or examiners (if you don't have one already)
2. Add a parameter to the dataset to filter by type
3. Tie the new parameter to @prmLimit
4. Add a second paramater that pulls from the second dataset.
5. Filter the results to the values in the second parameter.